# asp.net MVC 4 how to add data into table query

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So basically i have made table query "ProductTable" in my data connections
the query contains 4 rows ID,Name,Quantity and Price
all i want is to fill this table with data

in Table.aspx i have this :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Father.Models.ProductTable>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Table
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h1>Table</h1>
     <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
        <%: Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary() %>
    <fieldset>
        <ol>
            <li>
               <%: Html.LabelFor(z => z.ID) %>
               <%: Html.TextBoxFor(z => z.ID) %>
            </li>
            <li>
                 <%: Html.LabelFor(z => z.Name) %>
               <%: Html.TextBoxFor(z => z.Name) %>
            </li>
             <li>
                 <%: Html.LabelFor(z => z.Quantity) %>
               <%: Html.TextBoxFor(z => z.Quantity) %>
            </li>
             <li>
                 <%: Html.LabelFor(z => z.Price) %>
               <%: Html.TextBoxFor(z => z.Price) %>
            </li>


        </ol>

        <input type="submit" value="Enter" />
    </fieldset>
    <% } %>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">



</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ScriptsSection" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

In my Tablemodel :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace Father.Models
{



        public class ProductTable
        {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 

            public int ID { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public int Quantity { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public int Price { get; set; }
        }



}
```

in my TableController :

```
  public class TableController : Controller
    {


        public ActionResult Table()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Table(ProductTable zxc)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try 
                {


                }
                catch 
                { 

                }
            }
            return View(zxc);

        }

    }
```

What to write inside the controller so i can finally put my data into the table

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to spend some more time reading about the MVC paradigm vs. Web Forms. Take a look at Razor as well. You appear to be mixed up as to how everything is supposed to be happening.

You don't need the two methods in your controller.

```
public ActionResult Table() {
    var zxc = new ProductTable();
    // Load the data into the object.
    return View(zxc);
}
```

That method in your controller above will pass the ProductTable into the View you have at the top of the question as a **Model** which will then allow you to populate the data into the Labels and Textboxes that you have set up.

Your `HttpPost` method that you have there is for saving the data that is changed from the form. You will then validate that everything gets updated properly, and either send them back to another form (if the save was successful), or back to the `Table` view you have with the model back inside that includes any validation errors or other tips to the user.